# Groovy stops working when methodMissing() is implemented

Tags: groovy

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
class Foo {
    Foo() {}
    String boo() {
        def writer = new StringWriter()
        def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
        xml.records() {
            car(name:'HSV Maloo', make:'Holden', year:2006) {
                country('Australia')
                record(type:'speed', 'Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph')
            }
        }
        println writer
    }
    def methodMissing(String methodName, args) {
        println "Get called"
    }
}

Foo a = new Foo()
a.boo()
```

Result:

```
Get called
<records />
```

Without implementing `methodMissing()`, result:

```
<records>
  <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'>
    <country>Australia</country>
    <record type='speed'>Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph</record>
  </car>
</records>
```

I'm scratching my head bleeding now, what did I miss here?

Comment: It looks like inside the closures used by the MarkupBuilder, 'this' is still pointing to the containing class, so if a methodMissing is present, it "hides" the dynamic methods used by the builder since all unknown calls are redirected to the 'methodMissing' code. Other than that though, i cannot tell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when `boo()` is called, it creates a `MarkupBuilder` and eventually hits:

```
        car(name:'HSV Maloo', make:'Holden', year:2006) {
```

This checks for a `car` method in your class, and if one isn't found, it checks for one in the delegate of the `closure` (the MarkupBuilder).  The MarkupBuilder catches this, and generates an xml node.

However, you have defined `methodMissing`, so when it checks your class for the `car` method, it finds one and uses that instead (does nothing)

To fix this, you can specifically ask for the MarkupBuilder to be used by calling `xml.car()`, `xml.country()`, etc:

```
String boo() {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    xml.records() {
        xml.car(name:'HSV Maloo', make:'Holden', year:2006) {
            xml.country('Australia')
            xml.record(type:'speed', 'Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph')
        }
    }
    println writer
}
```